# How to use an IF statement for an entire column in Google Sheets?

Tags: google-sheets

I'm trying to create a neural network using the gem ruby-fann. In order for my data to work on that gem I need to convert it to binary. So for that column, it means I need to change any data less than or equal to 10 to "0" and greater than 10 to "1".

As you can see I have converted column C to binary using column D with `=IF(D2 >= 10, 1, 0)` and then dragging this down the column.

*However,* *I would like to dynamically apply this formula to my data in column D, that way I am left with only one column of binary that is based off column D.*

`=IF(D2:D396 >= 10, 1, 0)` returns 'an array value could not be found' and when I apply `=ARRAYFORMULA(IF(D2:D396 >= 10, 1, 0))` I receive an error return of 'Array result was not expanded because it would overwrite data in D2.'

I have also tried variations such as `=IF(D:D >= 10, 1, 0)`, `=IF(D2:D >= 10, 1, 0)`, or `=IF(D:D396 >= 10, 1, 0)`with no luck so far.

Any thoughts are appreciated.

[image: My sheet]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try placing the formula `=ARRAYFORMULA(IF(D2:D396 >= 10, 1, 0))` in cell `E2`.

The values you're trying to convert are in column D, so you can't place this formula in `D1` as you also want it to expand down the column. Placing it there would overwrite all of those source values. The "Array result was not expanded because it would overwrite data in D2" error is because the formula is actually unable to overwrite data. You can resolve the error by deleting the data in D2:D396, but again, you need that data.

Comment: So, what you're saying is that it's impossible to change the values of column D without leaving column D intact? Column C is already using a formula based on column D. I was hoping for a solution where column D is modified using an IF formula, resulting in D with new cell values based on the old cells, if possible.

Comment: @AlyHoop Trying to apply that formula with that approach is impossible. Assume you have the value 19 in cell D2. Applying your formula, the output is 1. But the formula replaces the value in D2 and 1 < 10, so now its output is 0. Because D2 is an input to the formula, it's going to continue calculating forever.